# Why my active admin shows errors which perfetly worked locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise, activeadmin

I am trying to add admin interface with `activeadmin` in my rails app. I have successfully completed locally but it gives error after deploying to heroku.
I have done all the things which is necessary for database migrations like:

```
heroku run rake db:create
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

I have changed the production to see the error:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = true
```

When I navigate to `[mysitename].herokuapp.com/admin` it gives the error like below:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in
>   ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#new
>
> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "admin_users" does not exist LINE
>   8: WHERE a.attrelid = '"admin_users"'::regclass ^ : SELECT a.attname,
>   format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid),
>   a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod, (SELECT c.collname FROM
>   pg_collation c, pg_type t WHERE c.oid = a.attcollation AND t.oid =
>   a.atttypid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation),
>   col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum) AS comment FROM pg_attribute a
>   LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum =
>   d.adnum WHERE a.attrelid = '"admin_users"'::regclass AND a.attnum > 0
>   AND NOT a.attisdropped ORDER BY a.attnum

And I clone my heroku and see if `admin_users` in `schema.rb` exists or not. I found there is `admin_users` table in `schema.rb`.

My `routes.rb` is:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  devise_for :users
  resources :users, only: :show
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
    resources :upvotes, only: :create
    resources :downvotes, only: :create
  end
  root 'posts#index'  
end
```

My `active_admin.rb` is:

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|

  config.site_title = "Instapost"

  config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!

  config.current_user_method = :current_admin_user

  config.logout_link_path = :destroy_admin_user_session_path

  config.comments = false

  config.comments_menu = false

  config.batch_actions = true

  config.localize_format = :long

  config.favicon = 'favicon.ico'

end
```

I have searched a lot. But any solutions could not solve this problem. If anybody know about this please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: The table was successfully created on heroku?

Comment: The table was not created on heroku..

Comment: You need to run `db:migrate` and see what's the error. You can obtain an interactive shell session by running `heroku run bash`.

Comment: The table already exists in the database. So that I have removed the migration created by active admin. When I run `rake db:migrate` no errors appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see the error, I tried a lot and finally succeed. The main error is

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "admin_users" does not exist

This says that relation `admin_users` does not exist. It means the migration is trying to change the `admin_users` which already existed in the table. But actually it does not exist in the table we have to create it.
Hence, in the migration file created by active admin `/db/migrate/xxxxxxxxxxxxx_add_devise_to_admin_users.rb`, replace `change` with `create` as `change_table :admin_users do |t|` with `create_table :admin_users do |t|`

Finally, push to the heroku and run `heroku run rake db:migrate`